# Cannot plot GAM, Error in array(np, 1) : 'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL' >

Tags: r, plot, gam

I was able to plot a generalized linear model in r.

Here is what I do:

```
library(faraway)
View(ozone)
mod.gam = gam(O3 ~ s(temp) + s(ibh) + s(ibt), data = ozone)
plot(mod.gam)
```

And here's the error:

```
Error in array(np, 1) : 'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
```

Have tried
- Restarting r
- Using the mgcv package as opposed to gam

I was able to plot it not to long ago, but I must have done something that prevents me from plotting.

Comment: I am using R 3.1.0 and gam package 1.09.1 and everything seems to work for me. Did you maybe change `ozone`? Or load some package (for example both plyr and faraway have data sets called ozone)?

Comment: I think that the error is that I loaded both the gam and the mgcv packages. The error went away when I restarted R and only loaded the mgcv package.